# how to create a nested json object in PHP5

Tags: php, json, nested

I know this is likely to be simple, but I am stuck and am unable to find a solution. I just want to create a simple nested json object that looks like the following:

```
{
   "user": {"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar","email":"foo.bar@somedomain.com"}
}
```

So far I can create the inner json as follows:

```
class user_profile {
    private $firstname = '';
    private $lastname ='';
    private $email = '';
    public function __construct($first, $last, $email){
        $this->firstname = $first;
        $this->lastname = $last;
        $this->email = $email;
    }
    public function expose() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

}
$up = new user_profile('foo','bar','foo.bar@somedomain.com');
echo json_encode($up->expose());
```

I tried adding an array:

```
echo json_encode(array('user',$up->expose()), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

but that results in:

```
{
    "0":"user","1":    {"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar","email":"foo.bar@somedomain.com"}
}
```

How do I create the outer "user" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `json_encode(array('user' => $up->expose());`

So basically the only mistake you made was using `,` instead of `=>`, which gave you an array with two objects, rather than an associative array with key => value.